# Hyperledger Fabric Node SDK and CA to use username and password

Tags: express, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm creating a Express.js REST server that can invoke and query chaincodes (similar to the JavaScript fabcar example). I'm wondering how would I register, enroll, and use a network user that is based on a username and password, so that I could allow the user to login using their username and password and can invoke chaincodes with their network user.

Please tell me if I'm going about this the wrong way, or if there are configs to achieve this.

Comment: Have you found any relevant documentation? Im looking for the same

Comment: @JasonShawnD'Souza I didn't find any documentation on how to implement this. However, I did implement my own authentication using passport.js, jwt, mongodb, and create a network user using the username for each of the user when it is registered.

Comment: Is there any documentation on to do with passport and mongo? If so please let me know !